# Robocopy skipping files

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

To copy presentations from a sharepoint to a backup location I mounted the library as a drive and copy the files from there. But annoyingly robocopy skips the files and I don't understand why. Can you help me? The Code is pretty straight forward:

```
:: Mounting SharePoint folder as network drive x:
net use x: "\\sharepoint.adress.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\dir\SL01"

:: Copying the files
call robocopy x: c:\test TEST.pptx

:: Unmount drive
net use x: /delete /yes
```

The filename is correct and robocopy does find the file but gets skipped every time. I have not found anything on google which would suggest that I need to set a special option to copy files. When I try to copy everything in the x: Drive it only copies the directories but no files.

Comment: Perhaps the file is already present in the target location. The source should be `x:\ ` (root of drive) rather than `x:`. Why are you using `call`? It is completely useless here!

Comment: The call is indeed useless. Copied the robocopy command from an older file and forgot to delete it. The file does not exist, the target folder is empty. If the Slash is needed, why will it still copy the folders but not the files If I try to copy everthing?

Comment: The backslash is not supposed to solve the problem, it simple ensures that you are pointing to the root directory of drive `x:`...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/MIR` as parameter.
This mirrors source- to target-folder.
But be careful, it also deletes files at target-folder which are delete at source-folder.

My problem was that `/NOCOPY` skips all files.
This command should only not copy file attributes.

http://www.computerhope.com/robocopy.htm